# How to add additional keyboard layouts in Manjaro?

Tags: keyboard-layout, manjaro

I am using the KDE version. With other distributions this is a piece of cake. I can't see any options for additional keyboards in the keyboard settings or locale..

Answer (score 14):

Open System Settings, choose "Input Devices", click on "layouts", add any language you want, and see the "alternate shortcut" you can change as you want and when you click the shortcut keys you choose. It will switch between the languages ​​you have added

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those shortcut assignments do not work for me, for some reason. I had to use `xkb-switch`, posted a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try from command line, there is utility called **keyboardctl** in Manjaro.

```
sudo keyboardctl -l us
```

It will change both the console and X11 keyboard layout.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply! That would mean that I have to do this every time I want to switch layouts, right? I would need a shortcut.

Comment: This utility seems to be no longer available in Manjaro.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today, in order to add a different layout you need to change the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` file.

```
    Section "InputClass"
            Identifier "system-keyboard"
            MatchIsKeyboard "on"
            Option "XkbLayout" "cz,us"
            Option "XkbModel" "pc104"
            Option "XkbVariant" ",dvorak"
            Option "XkbOptions" "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
    EndSection
```

You have to add there the other layouts in `Option "XkbLayout"` section. Also if you need a different variant of the keyboard you need to add `Option "XkbVariant" ",dvorak"` here the cz layout is default while the US is Dvorak. The last option: `Option "XkbOptions" "grp:alt_shift_toggle"` defines the keys which will be used to change the keyboard. A list of all available layouts can be found at: `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst`. After you do the changes you need to restart the X-server executing the command `sudo startx`. More information could be found at the ArchLinux [Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg_keyboard_configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/grwlf/xkb-switch .

Unfortunately, it's unavailable in Manjaro repos and the Arch/AUR package does not work.

You have to install it by hand:

1. Clone the repo locally.
2. Follow the intalling instructions.
3. `ldconfig` did not do the thing for me. I had to `sudo cp libxkbswitch.so.1 /usr/lib` .